# How to color mask high values on seaborn heat map

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, mask

I have a heatmap with a few very high values (>5) that I would like to mask red. I have been able to generate my heatmap no problem, but I can't figure out how to mask the high values.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='Lake Data.xlsx')

ws = wb['PC RFU']

data_rows = []
for row in ws['B77':'DL104']:
    data_cols  = []
    for cell in row:
        data_cols.append(cell.value)
    data_rows.append(data_cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
print(df)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop([0])

cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['float']).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')

print(df)
print(df.columns)
print(df.info())

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6))
f.suptitle('Site 03 PC/Chl', fontsize=16)

sns.heatmap(df.drop(['Depth (ft)'], axis='columns'), linewidths=0, ax=ax, cmap=color, robust='true', vmax=5) #,vmin=0,vmax=14, center=4

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Depth (Ft.)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The bright yellow squares on the right are actually between 5 and 15, and for those atypical high values >5 I'd like the squares to appear red. I can't seem to figure out how to use the mask feature to do this.

Bonus if someone can also tell me how to get rid of the "00:00:00" in the date axis!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom color map, and set its ["over"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_over) color to red. That way, all values larger than `vmax` will be colored red.

To restrict the x tick labels to their first 10 characters, you can use `t.get_text()[:10]`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 100).cumsum(axis=0),
                  columns=pd.date_range('20210101', freq='D', periods=100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6))
fig.suptitle('Site 03 PC/Chl', fontsize=16)

my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis').copy()
my_cmap.set_over('red')
sns.heatmap(df, linewidths=0, ax=ax, cmap=my_cmap, robust='true', vmax=5)

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax.set_xticklabels([t.get_text()[:10] for t in ax.get_xticklabels()], rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Depth (Ft.)')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: using an "over" color]

Additionally, you might add extra parameters to the [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), e.g. `sns.heatmap(..., cbar_kws={'pad': 0.02, 'extend': 'max', 'extendrect': True})`:

- `'pad': 0.02` to reduce the spacing between plot and colorbar
- `'extend': 'max'` to show the "over" color in the colorbar
- `'extendrect': True` to show the "over" color as a rectangle (default is a triangle)

PS: You might try [`pd.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to read the file directly and experiment with its parameters, in order to create the dataframe without manipulations.